# PCA project and backproject in Opencv

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv, computer-vision, pca

I am working in Ubuntu Opencv.I am trying to do PCA analysis of a single image.I take the 3 channel image and change it to a single channel image with 3 columns and r*c number of rows.r and c being the rows and columns of the original image.When I try to display the reconstructed image after doing the backprojection on the PCA it gives me a green image.Here is my code

```
Mat pcaset=cvCreateMat(image->height*image->width,image->nChannels,CV_8UC1);
for(int i=0;i<image->height;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<image->width;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<image->nChannels;k++)
            (ptrpcaset+i*pcaset.step)[k]=((ptrimage+i*image->widthStep)[3*j+k]);

       }

    }
int nEigens=3;
    Mat databackprojected;
    PCA pca(pcaset,Mat(),CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW,nEigens);
    Mat dataprojected(pcaset.rows,nEigens,CV_8UC1);
    pca.project(pcaset,dataprojected);
    pca.backProject(dataprojected,databackprojected);
    Mat backprojectnorm;//(databackprojected.rows,nEigens,CV_8UC1);
    normalize(databackprojected,backprojectnorm,0,255,NORM_MINMAX,-1);
    Mat finaldataafterreshaping(image->height,image->width,CV_8UC3);
    uchar* finalptr=(uchar*)finaldataafterreshaping.data;
    uchar* ptrnorm=(uchar*)backprojectnorm.data;

    int x=0,y=0,i=0;

    while(i<backprojectnorm.rows)
    {
        while(x<image->height)
        {
            while(y<image->width)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<image->nChannels;k++)
                {
                    (finalptr+x*finaldataafterreshaping.step)[3*y+k]=(ptrnorm+i*backprojectnorm.step)[k];
                }
                y=y+1;i=i+1;
            }
            x=x+1;y=0;
        }
    }
imshow("Reconstructed data",finaldataafterreshaping);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the following changes:

```
(ptrpcaset+(j + i*image->width)*pcaset.step)[k]=((ptrimage+i*image->widthStep)[3*j+k]);
```

because you are not taking the j coordinate into account when you transform your data so that at the end you only save the last line of your image in the new matrix.

When you reshape your data, you need to do something like this:

```
float* val = (float*)&(ptrnorm+i*backprojectnorm.step)[(k*4)];
(finalptr+x*finaldataafterreshaping.step)[3*y+k]=*val;
```

because the matrix you get as a result is of type `float` and not `uchar`. So you need to some kind of conversion. I am not sure, if it is a good idea to do it this way, but it works. I would suggest that you have a look at the C++ API of OpenCV 2, which can handle this things in a much nicer way.

Also, the whole `while(i<backprojectnrom.rows)` loop is not needed.

Comment: well I am trying to transform the 3 channel matrix into a n*3 matrix where each row represents the rgb value of the pixel.so if I do (ptrpcaset+(j + i*image->width)*pcaset.step)[k] how will this work

Comment: but `n` is supposed to be `width x height`? 
Currently you are addressing the rows of your destination matrix using the variable `i`. But `i` takes only values between 0 and `image->height`. So you can see that something is not right because you are not accessing a large amount of rows in the matrix you created.
So you need to take the variable `j` into account with something like this `(j + i*image->width)`. With this formula you get one unique index for each pair of (i,j). So you end up with exactly one row per pixel.